# Ruby on Rails routing issue, error message won't show up on redirect when using f.submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm creating a simple app that displays a student's properties stored in a database with a div element.

I can create, edit, and destroy records and I am using validations in my model to prevent empty/invalid records to be saved.

On my edit page if I try to update with invalid entries, the redirect flash[:notice] shows up, but when I try to create a new entry that is invalid, it just redirects me back to the main index page.

I've specifically stated under the create action in my controller that I want it to redirect it to the new_student page and flash the error message. What am I missing here?

Inside controller:

```
def create
    if @student = Student.create(params.require(:student).permit(
      :name, :weight, :height, :color, :gpa))
      redirect_to students_path
    else
      redirect_to(new_student_path, notice: "Invalid properties, are there any blanks?")
    end
  end
```

Inside model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :weight, :height, :color, :gpa
  validates_numericality_of :weight, :height, :gpa
  validates_inclusion_of :weight, in: 100..400
  validates_exclusion_of :weight, in: 0..100
  validates_inclusion_of :height, in: 135..225
  validates_exclusion_of :height, in: 0..135
end
```

Page where I submit, button is that the bottom:

```
<h1 class="pageTitle">Create a new student</h1>

<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :weight %><br/>
<%= f.number_field :weight %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :height %><br/>
<%= f.number_field :height %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :color %><br/>
<%= f.color_field :color %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :gpa %><br/>
<%= f.number_field :gpa %>
</div>

<div class="action">
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if there's more information that needs to be provided, I think that's sufficient.

Routes.rb just incase

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # get 'students/index'
  root :to => 'students#index'
  resources :students

  get '/new_student' => 'students#new'
  get '/all' => 'students#index', as: 'all_students'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you try:

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      redirect_to students_path
    else
      redirect_to(new_student_path, notice: "Invalid properties, are there any blanks?")
    end
  end

private
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(
      :name, :weight, :height, :color, :gpa)
  end
```

This works because there is a difference between `ActiveRecord#create`  `ActiveRecord#create!` and  `ActiveRecord#save`. `create` will return an initialized object if validation fails, remember that an initialized object is not `nil`, so your application would blindly assume that your record was saved, `create!` will raise an error while `save` would return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was a difference between these methods. Also thanks for the private student_params trick. I actually saw that elsewhere and tried it earlier but ran into some "unknown 'student_params'" error and figured it was more trouble than it was worth, but your syntax worked so clearly I was doing something wrong. One thing, though. In my new action, I already declare  
    
    @student = Student.new

Does that conflict or cause some kind of leak if I do that again in create?

Comment: No it doesn't affect your `create` action in any way. You should look at this for a better explanation on that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36820356/3893710

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `Student.create`. No mather the model instance you are going to create is valid or not, the create method always returns the object. Of course, in ruby it's true. Try to refactor your create method like below:

`def create
    @student = Student.new(params.require(:student).permit(
      :name, :weight, :height, :color, :gpa))
    if @student.save
      redirect_to students_path
    else
      redirect_to(new_student_path, notice: "Invalid properties, are there any blanks?")
    end
end`